# Undefined index em SELECT com INNER JOIN em tabela em PHP

Tags: php

Fiz um código PHP que faz o INNER JOIN de 4 tabelas, só que no outro código PHP que está dentro de um `<table>` está acontecendo vários erros.

- Erro

```
Notice: Undefined index: itens_venda.cd_itens_venda 
Notice: Undefined index: produto.nome 
Notice: Undefined index: funcionario.nome
Notice: Undefined index: cliente.nome
Notice: Undefined index: itens_venda.tipo_pagamento 
Notice: Undefined index: itens_venda.valor_item
Notice: Undefined index: itens_venda.quantidade
Notice: Undefined index: itens_venda.valor_total
Notice: Undefined index: itens_venda.data_venda
```

Alguém pode me auxiliar com esse problema.

- Código

```
<?php
        try {
            $selecao = "SELECT itens_venda.cd_itens_venda, produto.nome, funcionario.nome, cliente.nome, 
            itens_venda.tipo_pagamento, itens_venda.valor_item, itens_venda.quantidade, 
            itens_venda.valor_total, itens_venda.data_venda FROM itens_venda
            INNER JOIN produto ON (produto.cd_produto = itens_venda.cd_produto)
            INNER JOIN funcionario ON (funcionario.cd_funcionario = itens_venda.cd_funcionario)
            INNER JOIN cliente ON (cliente.cd_cliente = itens_venda.cd_cliente)";
            $seleciona_dados = $conexao->prepare($selecao);
            $seleciona_dados->execute();
            $linhas = $seleciona_dados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $falha_selecao) {
            echo "A listagem de dados não foi feita".$falha_selecao->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
    <table border="1">
        <tr> <td> ID <td> Produto <td> Funcionário <td> Cliente 
        <td> Pagamento <td> Valor item <td> Quantidade <td> Valor total <td> Data da venda </tr>
        <?php 
            foreach ($linhas as $exibir_colunas){
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['itens_venda.cd_itens_venda'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['produto.nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['funcionario.nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['cliente.nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['itens_venda.tipo_pagamento'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['itens_venda.valor_item'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['itens_venda.quantidade'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['itens_venda.valor_total'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['itens_venda.data_venda'].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>'; echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O nome da tabela não vai junto do nome dos campos nos resultados da consulta. Como alguns campos possuem o mesmo nome em diferentes tabelas, tive que adicionar aliases para eles. Seguem os ajustes:

```
    <?php
            try {
                $selecao = "
                     SELECT itens_venda.cd_itens_venda, 
                            produto.nome as nome_produto, 
                            funcionario.nome as nome_funcionario, 
                            cliente.nome as nome_cliente, 
                            itens_venda.tipo_pagamento,
                            itens_venda.valor_item, 
                            itens_venda.quantidade, 
                            itens_venda.valor_total, 
                            itens_venda.data_venda 
                     FROM itens_venda
                     INNER JOIN produto ON (produto.cd_produto = itens_venda.cd_produto)
                     INNER JOIN funcionario ON (funcionario.cd_funcionario = itens_venda.cd_funcionario)
                     INNER JOIN cliente ON (cliente.cd_cliente = itens_venda.cd_cliente)
                ";
                $seleciona_dados = $conexao->prepare($selecao);
                $seleciona_dados->execute();
                $linhas = $seleciona_dados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            } catch (PDOException $falha_selecao) {
                echo "A listagem de dados não foi feita".$falha_selecao->getMessage();
            }
        ?>
        <table border="1">
            <tr> <td> ID <td> Produto <td> Funcionário <td> Cliente 
            <td> Pagamento <td> Valor item <td> Quantidade <td> Valor total <td> Data da venda </tr>
            <?php 
                foreach ($linhas as $exibir_colunas){
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['cd_itens_venda'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['nome_produto'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['nome_funcionario'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['nome_cliente'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['tipo_pagamento'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['valor_item'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['quantidade'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['valor_total'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['data_venda'].'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>'; echo '</p>';
                }
            ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado Benilson, me ajudou muito.

Comment: Feliz em tem ajudado.